# Can I access the bitmap data created by CALayer.shouldRasterize = YES

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

If I understand it correctly, setting `CALayer.shouldRasterize = YES` generates a bitmap with the contents of the layer and its whole hierarchy of sublayers.

The documentation says:

> When the value of this property is YES, the layer is rendered as a bitmap in its local coordinate space and then composited to the destination with any other content.

Is there a way to access this bitmap's data? I would like to use it to generate a CIImage and apply a CIFilter without the need of drawing the whole layer into a new separate bitmap context and using the layer's method -renderInContext:.

Comment: There are a lot of assumptions and conflicting goals here. How would you use _data_ to generate a CIImage? Don't you want the CGImage? And if that's what you want, isn't that what `render(in:)` gives you? And in that case, what does all this have to do with rasterization? That part seems like a red herring.

Comment: @matt, the reason I do not want to use ````renderInContex:```` is performance. My CALayer is a property a UIView that contains a complex animation (sublayers). I want to apply a CIFilter to each animation frame. I thought rasterization means producing an accessible bitmap storage that could be used as a CGImage to finally apply filters. On macOS, CALayer has a .filters array, but on iOS, the only method I found was redrawing the layer to a separate bitmap context to get a CIImage. This is a slow process, good for static images but not for animated content.

Comment: Ok good answer, but then I’d say your goal is impossible this way. Rasterization won’t help.

Comment: Greg have you timed this? If so maybe show where the bottleneck is with code. I think renderInContext will be fast and expect that behind the scenes it just copies that internal bitmap you are after.

Comment: I voted up for this question, I found for certain properties such as `shadow`, the `render(in ctx: CGContext)` is not reliable on the generated image.